# Best way to avoid HTTP 403 error when getting Set-Cookie header to set CSRF Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api, x-xsrf-token

I'm calling a REST API that has CSRF protection.

Everything works well. I'm getting the token and sending it back to the server.

However, when I do the very first request or when the CSRF Cookie is not set in the browser it always throws an `HTTP 403` error.

This is because I didn't send `CSRF` token back given that this is the very first request in which the server sends the `Set-Cookie` header to set the CSRF Cookie.

What would be the best way to avoid this error the first time we send a request to a CSRF-protected API?

Should I check every time if the `CSRF` Cookie is set in the browser before sending any request?

Comment: You can create a custom endpoint something like /api?request=token which is not CSRF protected and returns the token only. Really depends how your API is programmed.

Comment: Does this mean that I'd have to check every time if I have the cookie set in order to send this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. This is a dummy script.

```js
checkIfAuthenticated()
.then( token => {
  // user is authorized. use token
})
.catch( err => {
  // oops. not authorized probably. authenticate user here.
});

// and your checkifAuthenticated:

function checkifAuthenticated() {
  return new Promise((resovle, reject) => {
    // perform a http request here to /api?checkauth
    if(api_returned_401) {
      reject('not authenticated');
    } else {
      resolve(tokenOrInfo);
    }
  });
}
```